# How many ARP Request/Reply for Ping command to work

Tags: linux, networking, ping, tcpdump

I would like know how many ARP Request/Reply are required for ping command to get work ?

Let's say we have two machines connected point to point with ip's 192.168.110.2 and 192.168.110.3 and executes ping command from machine 192.168.110.3

ping 192.168.110.2 -c 1

Now, how many ARP Requests/replies are required for this ping to successful ?

It is only one ARP Req and one ARP reply required in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory two, but in reality, one should suffice: the one sending its ping needs to know where to send it. The recipient needs to know where to send the reply, but should already have this info based on information received from the ping. Unless, ofcourse one or more of the computers involved have the relevant entries in their arp table.

Let's call the computer sending the ping A, and the target B.

1. A, knowing that it is a local connection (as in, doesn't need to be routed, based on its routing table), looks through its arp table for a match for computer B's IP.
2. When not found, A will broadcast an arp request. On wireshark i remember seeing this arp request as "Who has 192.168.0.123?" or something along those lines.
3. B will send an arp response (i do not remember if this was targetted or a broadcast. Most likely targetted)
4. At this point, A has everything it needs to send the ping.
5. B receives the ping, and does what needs to be done to formulate a response.
6. At this point, B probably already has A in its arp table, as it already received all of this info from the ICMP Ping packet. But for the purpose of this example, let's say it doesn't. In that case, it'll do the exact same thing as A did to begin with, so that it can send the response.

Comment: Ok Thanks , could you tell me how the sequence would look like.First ARP request would been seen at 192.168.110.2 then It would send ARP Reply, right ?

Comment: @AMIT answer updated.